# How to add two time(like 10:30:16,14:27:44) in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns as shown in below

```
InTime     OutTime
10:30:16   10:10:11
14:27:44   13:47:55
9:35:01    18:31:51
```

Now i need to sum intime column values and outtime column values seperatly then dofference between both output values in sql server 2008.Please any one help me.

**Output**:

```
Intime     Outtime
34:33:01   42:29:57
difference output:
7:56:56
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a data type for holding *time spans*, it only has a data type for holding a *time of day*. Since it doesn't make sense to add two times of day together, there's no built in support for adding these together. Could you read the results into another language that does support *time span* data? Or change the storage to something more appropriate (say just a number of seconds stored as an `int`)?

Answer (score 0):

SQL server specially don't have any function to add and subtract time but if you need you can use

```
DATE_SUB()
DATE_ADD()
```

By putting same date in each time 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp

Answer (score 0):

Because `Sql Server` `time` type may contain up to 24 hours you can return `varchar` type as:

```
select cast(tm / 3600 as varchar(20)) + ':' +
cast((tm - tm % 60) / 60 % 60 as varchar(20)) + ':' +
cast(tm % 60 as varchar(20))
from (select sum(datediff(ss, timein, timeout)) tm from t) t
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f20de/19

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like that. It is not nice but you can write help functions to format data (select return nvarchar becouse time in sql server can not reach more then 24 h):

```
        create table #TMP
        (
           InTime time,
           OutTime time
        )

        INSERT INTO #TMP (InTime, OutTime) VALUES ('10:30:16', '10:10:11')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (InTime, OutTime) VALUES ('14:27:44', '13:47:55')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (InTime, OutTime) VALUES ('9:35:01', '18:31:51')

        select  CAST(InTime/3600 as nvarchar(5))  + ':' + CASE WHEN ((InTime%3600)/60) > 9 THEN '' ELSE '0' END +  CAST((InTime%3600)/60 as nvarchar(5)) + ':' + CASE WHEN ((InTime%3600)%60) > 9 THEN '' ELSE '0' END + CAST((InTime%3600)%60 as nvarchar(5)) as SumIn,
                CAST(OutTime/3600 as nvarchar(5)) + ':' + CASE WHEN ((OutTime%3600)/60) > 9 THEN '' ELSE '0' END + CAST((OutTime%3600)/60 as nvarchar(5)) + ':' + CASE WHEN ((OutTime%3600)%60) > 9 THEN '' ELSE '0' END+ CAST((OutTime%3600)%60 as nvarchar(5)) as SumOut,
                CAST(Diff/3600 as nvarchar(5))    + ':' + CASE WHEN ((Diff%3600)/60) > 9 THEN '' ELSE '0' END + CAST((Diff%3600)/60 as nvarchar(5)) + ':' + CASE WHEN ((Diff%3600)%60) > 9 THEN '' ELSE '0' END+ CAST((Diff%3600)%60 as nvarchar(5)) as Diff 
            from 
            (
            select SUM(datediff(SECOND, '00:00:00', InTime)) as InTime, SUM(datediff(SECOND, '00:00:00', OutTime)) as OutTime,
            SUM(datediff(SECOND, '00:00:00', OutTime)) - SUM(datediff(SECOND, '00:00:00', InTime)) as Diff
             from #TMP
            ) X
```

CASE is for format data to have 34:33:01 not 34:33:1

Answer (score 0):

There isn't built-in function on this.
But You can use this:

```
declare @t table (InTime time, OutTime time)
insert into @t values 
('10:30:16', '10:10:11')
, ('14:24:44', '13:47:55')
, ('9:35:01', '18:31:51')

select convert(varchar(10),t.InTime/60/60)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar(2),(t.InTime-t.InTime%60)/60%60),2)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar(2),t.InTime%60),2) InTime
  , convert(varchar(10),t.OutTime/60/60)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar(2),(t.OutTime-t.OutTime%60)/60%60),2)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar(2),t.OutTime%60),2) OutTime
  , convert(varchar(10),t.DiffTime/60/60)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar(2),(t.DiffTime-t.DiffTime%60)/60%60),2)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar(2),t.DiffTime%60),2) DiffTime
from (
  select sum(DATEPART(HOUR,InTime)*60*60 + DATEPART(MINUTE, InTime)*60 + DATEPART(SECOND, InTime)) InTime
    , sum(DATEPART(HOUR,OutTime)*60*60 + DATEPART(MINUTE, OutTime)*60 + DATEPART(SECOND, OutTime)) OutTime
    , sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND, InTime, OutTime)) DiffTime
  from @t) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this first calculate Intime and outTime sums in Seconds then get diffrences between both outtime - Intime .

```
SELECT cast( (TimeInseconds / 3600 ) AS varchar(10) ) +  ':' +
        cast( ((TimeInseconds % 3600) / 60)as  varchar(10)) + ':' +
        cast( (TimeInseconds % 60) AS varchar(10)) As Time
    FROM (
        SELECT (SUm(DatePart(HH, OutTime)) * 3600 + SUm(DatePart(MINUTE, OutTime)) * 60 + SUm(DatePart(SS, OutTime))) - (SUm(DatePart(HH, Intime)) * 3600 + SUm(DatePart(MINUTE, Intime)) * 60 + SUm(DatePart(SS, Intime))) AS TimeInseconds
        FROM Intimes
        ) X
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75694/2)